# Error-free AndEngine examples crashing

Tags: android, andengine

I am getting started with AndEngine, and I'd like to use some of the AndEngineExamples included on GitHub as a basis to work from. Now, I've downloaded everything on GitHub and Eclipse gives no errors on any of the extensions or the examples. However, when I try to launch AnalogOnScreenControlsExample it crashes and I get the following error log:

```
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.andengine.examples/org.andengine.examples.launcher.ExampleLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.andengine.examples.launcher.ExampleLauncher
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.andengine.examples.launcher.ExampleLauncher
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
12-02 14:36:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     ... 11 more
```

Looking at this I think the problem is in ExampleLauncher, but I checked and I found that the class is there and is error-free. So what can the problem be? I hope you guys have an idea how to fix this.

Comment: Can you please share sample project link..,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
1) Running Project clean and rebuilding it
2) Running it on a physical device rather than on an emulator

Comment: I was already running it on a physical device. But cleaning the project worked :) . It's weird though, because I had cleaned it earlier and then it still crashed. Anyways, it works now so thanks!